# Event Listener for Children

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

Say I have a list of children within a list and want to perform an action when one of the children of the list is clicked.

```
<ul id="list">
    <li id="item1">1</li>
    <li id="item2">2</li>
    <li id="item3">3</li>
    <li id="item4">4</li>         
</ul>
```

I would use document.getElementById("list").children to get an array of the children, but how do I register them with an event listener after getting the array?

Comment: Just iterate over the array? A better approach might be to just register the handler on the `ul` element though.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to call `addEventListener` in a loop:

```js
Array.from(document.getElementById("list").children).forEach(c => c.addEventListener("click", e => console.log(`Clicked on ${e.currentTarget.id}`)));
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li id="item1">1</li>
    <li id="item2">2</li>
    <li id="item3">3</li>
    <li id="item4">4</li>         
</ul>
```

Another way is to add the listener on the container. The event will bubble up, and you can use `event.target` to get the specific element that was clicked on.

```js
document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("click", e => console.log(`Clicked on ${e.target.id}`));
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li id="item1">1</li>
    <li id="item2">2</li>
    <li id="item3">3</li>
    <li id="item4">4</li>         
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok perfect! So if I wanted to create an anonymous function inside of the listener just take out the ```e => console.log(`Clicked on ${e.currentTarget.id}`)``` and replace it with function() {code in here} and manipulate the elements using the variable c?

Comment: `e =>` is an anonymous arrow function.

Comment: If you want a multiline function, just use `e => { ... }`.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you! I am relatively new to Javascript so i'm a little confused on some stuff!

Comment: Can you change the attribute of a "currentTarget" such as ```e.currentTarget.height *= 2``` for example?

Comment: Of course. It's a DOM element, you can do anything you want to it.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let AllLis = document.querySelectorAll("li");

AllLis.forEach( li => {
  li.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    li.innerHTML -= 1;
  })
})
```

```css
li{
padding:1rem;
margin:.5rem
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li id="item1">1</li>
    <li id="item2">2</li>
    <li id="item3">3</li>
    <li id="item4">4</li>         
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do `document.querySelectorAll("li");` and then create a Event listener for each of those object.